# Convergence of Glaisher-Kinkelin Constant Limit Definitions

Tags: limits

The Glaisher-Kinkelin constant $A$ is given by the limits
$$\begin{align}
A&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{H(n)}{n^{n^2/2+n/2+1/12}e^{-n^2/4}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2\pi)^{n/2}n^{n^2-1/12}e^{-3n^2/4+1/12}}{G(n+1)}
\end{align}$$
where $H(z)$ is the hyperfactorial function and $G(z)$ is the Barnes G-Function. How would you prove these limits converge?

Comment: The first one can be done via the Euler Maclaurin formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have 
$$  A = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2\pi)^{n/2} n^{n^2\mathbf{\underline{/2}}-1/12} \mathrm{e}^{-3n^2/4+1/12}}{G(n+1)}  \text{.}  $$

I would write your first version with $K(n+1)$ in the numerator, where $K$ is the [K-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-function).  That the two limits converge together or diverge together follows from the identity 
$$  K(n) = \frac{(\Gamma(n))^{n-1}}{G(n)}  \text{.}  $$
(Use Stirling's approximation to replace the $\Gamma$ function with the powers of $n$ and $\mathrm{e}$ appearing in the fractions.  Note that the denominator in your first limit grows rapidly enough that the error term in Stirling's approximation cannot be large enough to alter the limit.)  So if you can show either converges you show both converge.

Then show the version with the [Barnes $G$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function) is positive and monotonically decreasing, so the limit exists.  (Most of the numerator cancels with the definition of the Barnes $G$-function.  Positivity is easy.  Monotonicity comes from analysis of the derivative with respect to $n$, which is 
$$  \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-3 n^2/4 + 1/12} n^{n^2/2-13/12} \left(3\
   2^{n/2+1} n \pi ^{n/2} (2 n \log (n)-2 n \psi ^{(0)}(n+1)+1)-(2 \pi
   )^{n/2}\right)}{12 G(n+1)}  \text{,}  $$
where $\psi^{(0)}$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) of order $0$, also known as the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).  To get monotonically decreasing, we only have to show that the expression in the large parentheses is (eventually) negative.  Show that the derivative of the expression in parentheses has one zero, near $n = 2$ and compare the signs of this derivative to show that critical point is a maximum.  Then observe that the parenthesized expression is negative, $< -1/8$, at that maximum and you are done.)